# Overhead caused while fetching the required client in WAMP WS

Tags: python, python-2.7, autobahn, autobahnws

I have created a websocket server using the WAMP WS provided in python programming language.

I have a requirement where I am subscribing about 500 clients with the WAMP WS server at a time.

But when I am publishing the data I will send it only to a single client based on certain conditions. I know that it is very much simple to just loop throgh the list of cliets and find out the eligible and then send the data to that respective client.

I would like to know, is there any other way without using the loops, as using loops will lead to a large overhead if in case the required client is at the last position.

Answer (score 0):

presumably you loop through each client's eligibility data and do some sort of decision based on that data.  it would follow that an index on the eligibility data would give you near instant access. so, using pseudo code, something like:

```
client_array = []
client_index = {}
client_array.add(new client)
if not new client.eligibility_data in client_index:
    client_index[new client.eligibility_data] = []
client_index[new client.eligibility_data].add(new client)
```

I don't know what the eligibility data is, but, say it is the weight of the client.  If you wanted to send a message to everybody that weighs between 200 and 205 points you could find those clients in the client_index[200] through [205].

if the condition cannot be determined before hand then you may need a database which can handle arbitrary queries to determine the client targets.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a [publish](http://autobahn.ws/python/reference/autobahn.wamp.html#autobahn.wamp.interfaces.IPublisher.publish), you can provide a list of eligible receivers for the event via [options](http://autobahn.ws/python/reference/autobahn.wamp.html#autobahn.wamp.types.PublishOptions), e.g. similar to [this](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/examples/twisted/wamp/basic/pubsub/options/backend.py#L45). The list of eligible receiver should be specified as a list of WAMP session IDs (which is the correct way to identify WAMP clients in this case).

Internally, AutobahnPython uses Python sets and set operations to compute the actual receivers - which is quite fast (and built into the language .. means native code runs).